# How To Turn Off Mac’s Monitor screen

Tags: mac, sleep-wake, display

How can I turn off tmy Mac's monitor. I know I can turn off the display by setting a hot cornet or by using ctrl + shift + Eject but I dont want this.
I want to leave my Mac on and connect to it via teamViewer from another place but when I do that the Mac's display turn's on. I do this with my PC in the office, I leave my PC on but I simple turn off the monitor by pushing the button on the bottom right corner :) this means my PC is still on but the monitor is off and it does not show anything on the screen. I do this sometime in case I have to connect to my PC from home, but without letting anyone know that my PC is on!

UPDATED:
Sorry for not being clear,
It is "iMac" OS X version 10.8.5

Can I do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't describe what kind of Mac it is, but I'll assume an iMac or MacBook of some flavor. If you had a Mac Mini or a Pro with a third party monitor then you probably wouldn't be asking this question.

You can't do exactly what you want with an iMac, but if you use "Apple Remote Desktop" ([App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-remote-desktop/id409907375), $80) you can lock the screen so anybody sitting at your computer can't see what you are doing. This doesn't seem to be possible with the built in screen sharing.

The Apple Remote Desktop option is more secure, since you can't be sure that nobody turned your PC monitor on after you leave work.

Comment: The problem though is Apple Remote Desktop is intended for local networks, not for connecting to the office network from home for example.  Technically it IS possible but I've always seen mixed results and more failure than success stories.

Comment: I connect to my home server via ARD without any problems. If you are trying to access a machine that is behind a firewall, then that can cause problems for ARD.

Comment: Thanks for your answer....I dont want to spend £62 on this... I was looking for the free solution...This means I cannot do that :)

Comment: I know it's an expensive solution for something like this, but it's the only solution I know of.